# Find a file extension

Tags: command-line, windows-server

We hold a file on a server where we store a version number.  Now we update the file extension with that version number (not my choice and not something I can change).

So what I need to be able to do in a batch file is to read that file extension.  I know the path to the file and the filename, but need to be able to determine what the extension currently is.

Answer (score 1):

you can search with a wildcard character `*` to find the file

```
dir file.txt.* /s /p
```

Comment: That might indeed work.  I shall try this out.  Thanks.

Comment: A bit overkill, since he knows the path there's no need to list matches in subdirectories.  The output will likely be the same though